# Copy An Event From iPhoto

Tags: photos.app

Is there a way to copy just the contents of a single event from iPhoto to another location?

When I want to zip up all of the photos in a single event and move them somewhere, like to a USB drive, I have to look at the event photos, click a photo, then choose File->Show In Finder, then select, copy, and zip the folders containing the event photos I want. This seems like way too many steps for what seems like a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply drag the event out of iPhoto to the destination folder  ;)

If you really want to zip them, use the [Export to archive](http://joeygibson.com/2007/08/29/export-to-archive-iphoto-plugin/) iPhoto plugin.

Comment: I feel silly now. I knew there had to be an easy way that I hadn't thought of. I kept looking for a menu item. Thanks!